# Wrong position of parttitle

Tags: tikz-pgf, parts, pgfornament

I am trying my best to make a beatiful ornament on partpage, but position of parttitle is awful in my every trying. It should be under words "PART I".

I tried to define newcommand `\parttitle` to catch parttitle (I mean words "I AM HERE"), but nothing happens, and even then phrase "I AM HERE" will be repeated two times. That's awful too.

Maybe it is too easy, then sorry.

Please, take a look at the screenshot:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{pgfornament}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\framesize}{\textwidth}

\titleformat{\part}
[display]
{\centering\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}
{\begin{tikzpicture}[color=black,
transform shape,
every node/.style={inner sep=0pt}]
\node[minimum size=\framesize,fill=white!10](vecbox){};
\node[inner sep=6pt] (text) at (vecbox.center){\MakeUppercase{\Huge \partname\ \thepart}};
\node[anchor=north] at (text.south){%
\pgfornament[width=0.75*\framesize]{75}};
\node[anchor=south] at (text.north){%
\pgfornament[width=0.75*\framesize,symmetry=h]{75}};
\end{tikzpicture}\vspace{3pt}}
{0pt}
{\huge\MakeUppercase}

\begin{document}
\part{I am here}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think Ti*k*Z is helpful here. It just adds unnecessary complications. Why can't you just say something like this?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{pgfornament}
\newcommand{\framesize}{\textwidth}
\titleformat{\part}
  [display]
  {\centering\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}
  {%
    \mbox{\pgfornament[width=0.75\framesize,symmetry=h]{75}}
    \vskip 3pt
    \MakeUppercase{\Huge \partname\ \thepart}%
  }
  {3pt}
  {\huge\MakeUppercase}
  [%
  \mbox{\pgfornament[width=0.75\framesize]{75}}%
  ]

\begin{document}
\part{I am here}
\end{document}
```

[image: fancy part page]